# Meteor + existing mongo : Data added through GUI not visible in database

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to use an existing mongo instance for my meteor app (example simple-todos app with form submission).

**simple-todos.html**

```
<head>
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>

      <form class="new-task">
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type to add new tasks" />
      </form>

    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="task">
  <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

**simple-todos.js**

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Meteor.subscribe("tasks-broadcast");

  Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function(){
        return Tasks.find();
    }
  });

  Template.body.events({
    "submit .new-task": function (event) {
      // Prevent default browser form submit
      event.preventDefault();

      // Get value from form element
      var text = event.target.text.value;

      // Insert a task into the collection
      Tasks.insert({
        text: text,
        createdAt: new Date() // current time
      });

      // Clear form
      event.target.text.value = "";
    }
  });

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
    Meteor.publish("tasks-broadcast", function() {
      return Tasks.find({},{ sort: { timestamp:-1}, limit: 20});
    });
  });
}
```

I have reset the MONGO_URL path using :

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/simple-todos
```

When I submit an item from a client, the todo list updates on all clients. So the data is being added and retrieved properly. However, when I check the mongo instance running through the terminal, I don't see any collection `tasks` there. I am clueless about where exactly the data is getting persisted. And how can I confirm if the data is actually going to the local mongo?

Please help, thanks.

**EDIT :** 
The application is not running on the local mongo. When I do `meteor mongo` in the project folder I get this

> mongo: Meteor isn't running a local MongoDB server.

Comment: How are you checking the local mongo instance? Are you running `meteor mongo` from your app directory? It could be you have >1 mongo running.

Comment: @MichelFloyd : Yes, please see the edit.

Comment: From the *mongo shell* type `use mydb` where `mydb` is the name of your db in mongo.

Comment: I'm doing `use simple-todos` in mongo shell. There is no collection names 'tasks'